# Intellij IDEA - запуск проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть вопрос.Как запускать некоторые проекты в IDEA?нажимаю на run,а высвечивается - 0.edit Configurations.что это такое?

Comment: [читаем](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 - это код возврата, означает что команда/функция выполнилась успешно.
Ваша java программа что-то пишет в консоль? Видимо нет, поэтому и выводится только "Process finished with exit code 0".
Edit Configuration - для настройки запуска вашего проекта, в частности, вы можете указать класс содержащий метод main и обозвать это конфигурацию, например conf1. При запуске с этой конфигурацией, программа будет стартовать с метода main указанного в настройках. Так же можно задавать различные настройки для запуска программы, для начала достаточно только указать класс где находится метод main (IDEA по умолчанию находит его сама)

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F10`, либо ПКМ нажимаешь и `Run`.